# How to store a list of strings in a single ZooKeeper znode using Curator

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

For example, there is a znode path `A/B/C/D`.
I'd like to store a list of Strings on that znode.
Obviously, I could use join a list of strings into the single string and then serialize it into byte array like this:

```
curator.create()
            .creatingParentContainersIfNeeded()
            .forPath(path, value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

But this looks not very convenient.
Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest/best way to do it is probably to use ApacheUtils:

```
byte[] input = SerializationUtils.serialize(yourList);
curator.create()
        .creatingParentContainersIfNeeded()
        .forPath(path, input);
```

and to get it out:

```
byte[] output = curator.getData().forPath(path);
List<String> newList = (List<String>)SerializationUtils.deserialize(output);
```

This is a rather general aproach that will work with most java objects.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

You may use Json serialization to store byte stream of list to node if that helps.
I used jackson library for the same.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList("First", "Second");
try
{
    byte[] writeValueAsBytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(inputList);
    curatorFramework.setData().forPath(zPath, writeValueAsBytes);
    byte[] outputBytes = curatorFramework.getData().forPath(zPath);
    List<String> outputList = mapper.readValue(outputBytes, ArrayList.class);
    System.out.println(outputList);
} catch (Exception exception)
{
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
[First, Second]
```

I hope this is also helpful to someone.